# Build docker with Rust Microservices System

Tags: microservices, backend, rust-cargo, rust-language-server

I'm building a Microservices Rust project with Cargo Workspace and Cargo Make. How to implement this project with docker, I want to structure the project like the below image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLa2O.png)

I did configure it but failed